# How to pass js variable to Rails function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to pass a js(Angular) variable to Rails?

*JSON*

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Test","selected":false,"url":"http://localhost:3000/vacancies/1.json"}]
```

__

*view*

```
%div{"ng-repeat"=>"vacancy in vacancies"} # From Angular via JSON
  - vacancy = Vacancy.find(vacancy.id) # I need to get a record here
```

I have this an error `undefined method id for nil:NilClass`

*vacancies* array is woriking fine

If this is impossible maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you're trying to achieve is not impossible, but there <del>are two things that are off</del> is one thing that is off with your current approach:

- <del>You cannot perform an ActiveRecord query (i.e. `Vacancy.find(...)`) from within the view template. This action is typically performed from within the controller.</del> **Total brain cramp on my part -- it's definitely possible :P**
- You are attempting to mix Angular scopes with interpreted Ruby code. The reason you're getting the `nil:NilClass` exception is because in the scope of that Ruby code, there's no defined "vacancy" variable, even though it's defined in Angular's scope.

The way you could achieve the retrieval of Vacancy objects is through an API layer set up to communicate between your Rails database backend and your AngularJS frontend. The process could look something like:

- Define dedicated routes for your api in your Rails routes.
- Set up an Angular controller which triggers a GET request to your specific API route.
- Once that route is hit, your specific Rails controller action kicks in, which can fetch your Vacancy objects, and return a JSON response.
- Then, your Angular code can handle the provided response to assign the returned vacancies JSON object to `$scope.vacancies`.
- Then you can do `ng-repeat` in your view and you'll have the full Vacancy objects within your `vacancies` collection, without having to fetch each one as a separate request.

I think [this article](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-ruby-on-rails/consuming-rest-apis.html) can give you a clearer example to work off of.

There's a decent amount of information to cover on the subject of integrating Rails with AngularJS, and I know you didn't ask for this specifically, but this book covers the basics of integrating Rails and Angular quite well. [**AngularJS + Rails**](https://leanpub.com/angularails).

Comment: Actually I can perform query from within the view template. It works everything :)

Thank you for links.

Comment: It's no problem! I hope it was helpful! I edited my answer to strike out the incorrect first bullet point - no idea why I wrote that it couldn't be done :P Thanks for the feedback!